# Prevent dropping to div if it's not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery UI `.droppable` for dropping elements to divs. Now I need to prevent dropping to divs with class `.box` if they are not empty.

I tried:

```
if ($('.box').is(':empty')) {
    $(".box").droppable({

    });
}
```

But this makes all `.box` divs non-droppable whether they are empty or not.

Comment: Maybe try using the `.preventDefault()` method. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: The code above your basically saying,.. If any `.box` has any `:empty` then all `.box` will be droppable..  You could maybe do ->  `$(".box:empty").droppable({})`

Comment: @Keith unfortunately, your code does the same

Answer (score 0):

The code below will check, does element with class `box` has any text or other elements inside. You can try to put text or add child elements to that div to be sure, that it's working:

```js
if (!$('.box').text() && $('.box').children().length === 0) {
  console.log("droppable");
  /*$(".box" ).droppable({
    // code here
  });*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: @Igor234, may be you're using `.droppable` in wrong way

Comment: I use it like that `$(".box").droppable({`. The code in your answer works. In DOM Inspector I see that the div is empty, but still non-droppable

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is:

```
$(".box").droppable({
    accept: function() {
        return $(this).find("*").length == 0;
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.append(ui.draggable.css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }));
    }
});
```